# To understand the inner working of query execution

Tags: database, postgresql

In MySql SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G available to understand the inner working of query execution. I want to know equivalent for this in postgres

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of information from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS reports are stored in few postgresql stat tables (Some not - are not available or has no sense on Postgres due different architecture).

You can try to look to basic views:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_databases;
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_indexes;
SELECT * FROM pg_locks;
```